# finding next leap year java

Tags: java, date, for-loop, while-loop, leap-year

The code works when the first year is a leap year so if I said the year was 2004 it would return 2008, but when the starting year is not a leap year, it returns nothing. How would I output that if, for ex: the given year was 2001, 2002, or 2003, the next leap year would be 2004. I know the while loop makes sense but I don't know what to put inside it. ALSO I can only use basic java formatting so no inputted classes like  java.time.Year

```
public static boolean leapYear(int year) {
  boolean isLeap = true;
  if (year % 4 == 0) {
    if (year % 100 == 0) {
      if (year % 400 == 0)
        isLeap = true;
      else
        isLeap = false;
    } else
      isLeap = true;
  } else {
    isLeap = false;
  }
  return isLeap;
}

public static int nextLeapYear(int year) {
  int nextLeap = 0;

  if (leapYear(year)) {
    nextLeap = nextLeap + 4;
  } else {
    while (!leapYear(year)) {
      nextLeap++;
    }
    nextLeap += 1;
  }
  year += nextLeap;
  return year;
}
```

Comment: You may also accept your own answer (after a time, I think 12 hours).

Comment: If this is an exercise, it’s a good one. For production code one would not and should not make one’s own leap year calculation, but should leave it to [`Year.isLeap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#isLeap--) or another good library method.

Answer (score 2):

Granted this doesn't take much processing.  But if you want to increase the efficiency of your program you might consider the following:

- All leap years must be divisible by 4.  But not all years divisible by 4 are leap years.  So first, check for not divisible by 4. That will be 75% of the cases. In that event, return `false`.

```
   if (year % 4 != 0) {
        return false;
   }
```

- As you continue, the `year must be divisible by 4` so just make certain it is **not** a century year.  This will be evaluated 25% of the time and will return true 24% of the time.

```
   if (year % 100 != 0) {
       return true;
   }
```

- lastly, the only category not checked are years divided by 400. If we got here in the logic, then it must be a century year.  So return accordingly. This will evaluate to true .25% of the time.

```
  return year % 400 == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is broken in multiple ways:

1. You say: If the given year is a leap year, then the next leap year will be 4 years later. **This is false**. If you pass in 1896, your algorithm returns 1900, but this is wrong; whilst 1896 is a leap year, 1900 is not.
2. Your isLeapYear code would be miles easier to read if you early-exit. That method should have a lot of return statements and fall less indentation.
3. Your while loop will keep asking the same question over and over, and if you ask the same question to a stable method (and your isLeapYear method is stable), you get the same answer, resulting in an infinite loop. Presumably, you don't want `while(!leapYear(year))`, you want `while(!leapYear(year + nextLeap))`, and you don't want to increment nextLeap once more after the while loop.
4. in fact, your edge case of: If the stated year is already a year, add 4 - is not necessary at all. Think about it: You can just eliminate that if/else part. Your code will just be `nextLeap`, that while loop, and a return statement. a 3-liner, if you do right.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm still learning so I can take all the suggestions. However, I took  your advice and changed the code to                                                                                             
                    int nextLeap = 0;
       while(leapYear(year + nextLeap) == false){
        nextLeap++;
      
       }
   year += nextLeap;
   return year;            But while it worked when the given year was NOT a leap year, it did not return to me the next leap year when the given year WAS a leap year. So wouldn't I need some sort of if statement?

Comment: No, you don't. You need to change 1 character.... :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I figured it out yay!

for anybody struggling w/ this, this is what worked for me :)

```
public static boolean leapYear(int year) {
    if(year % 4 == 0)
    {
        if( year % 100 == 0)
        {
            // year is divisible by 400, hence the year is a leap year
            if ( year % 400 == 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
    }



public static int nextLeapYear (int year) {
    int nextLeap = 0;
         while(leapYear(year + nextLeap) == false){
             nextLeap++;
        
         }
        
        if(leapYear(year) == true)
            nextLeap += 4;
        
        year += nextLeap;
        return year;

    }
```

Comment: It’s a leap forward. `nextLeapYear(2096)` returns 2100, but 2100 will not be a leap year (and `leapYear(2100)` correctly returns false).

Comment: Get in the habit of putting braces (`{}`) around your return statements and other any other single statement actions that could go into a block.  It will save you debugging time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> Every year that is exactly divisible by four is a leap year, except
> for years that are exactly divisible by 100, but these centurial years
> are leap years if they are exactly divisible by 400. For example, the
> years 1700, 1800, and 1900 are not leap years, but the years 1600 and
> 2000 are.
> [- United States Naval Observatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar)

You can greatly simplify the function, `leapYear` as shown below:

```
public static boolean leapYear(int year) {
  return year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0);
}
```

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(leapYear(1999));
        System.out.println(leapYear(2000));
        System.out.println(leapYear(1900));
        System.out.println(leapYear(1904));
    }

    public static boolean leapYear(int year) {
        return year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
true
false
true
```

Then, you can use it in the function, `nextLeapYear` as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(nextLeapYear(1999));
        System.out.println(nextLeapYear(2000));
        System.out.println(nextLeapYear(2001));
    }

    public static int nextLeapYear(int year) {
        // If year is already a leap year, return year + 4
        if (leapYear(year)) {
            return year + 4;
        }

        // Otherwise, keep incrementing year by one until you find a leap year
        while (!leapYear(year)) {
            year++;
        }

        return year;
    }

    public static boolean leapYear(int year) {
        return year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2000
2004
2004
```

In production code, you should use the OOTB (Out-Of-The-Box) class, [`java.time.Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) to deal with a year.

```
import java.time.Year;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(nextLeapYear(1999));
        System.out.println(nextLeapYear(2000));
        System.out.println(nextLeapYear(2001));
    }

    public static int nextLeapYear(int year) {
        Year yr = Year.of(year);
        // If year is already a leap year, return year + 4
        if (yr.isLeap()) {
            return yr.plusYears(4).getValue();
        }

        // Otherwise, keep incrementing year by one until you find a leap year
        while (!yr.isLeap()) {
            yr = yr.plusYears(1);
        }

        return yr.getValue();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2000
2004
2004
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.